# How to apply filter feature selection in datasets with various data types?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have recently been looking into different filter feature selection approaches and have noted that some are better suited for numerical data (Pearson) and some are better suited for categorical data (Chi-Square).

I am working with a dataset with a mixture of both data types and am unsure about what the best practice is in terms of applying the filter methods.

Is it best to split the dataset into categorical and numerical, performing different filter methods on each set and then joining the results?

Or should only one filter method be applied to the whole dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Permutation Importance. The idea is to randomly shuffle the values of a feature and observe the change in error. If the feature is important, ideally the error should increase. It does not depend on the data type of the feature, unlike some statistical tests. Also it is very straightforward to implement and analyze. [link1](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blackbox/permutation_importance.html), [link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-importance-with-neural-network-346eb6205743)